# VueJS Form validation with VeeValidate, can't type on some mobile devices

Tags: forms, vue.js, vee-validate

We have a weird problem in a form that is validated with `Vee-Validate` 
We have an input:

```
 <input
            v-validate="'required|name'"
            id="firstName"
            v-model="firstName"
            :class="{'is-invalid': errors.has('firstName'), 'filled': firstNameFilled}"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="firstName">
          <label for="firstName">Vorname*</label>
```

Following Script:

```
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
          formData: 'registration/formData'
        }),
     firstNameFilled () {
         return this.formData.firstName !== null
        },
      firstName: {
         get () {
            return this.formData.firstName
         },
      set (data) {
        this.$store.dispatch('registration/updateFormData', { firstName: 
          data })
        }
       },
     methods: {
       async validate () {
          this.registrationButtonDisabled = true
         try {
            const needCaptcha = this.$route.query.utm_campaign && 
           this.$route.query.utm_campaign.includes('display');
          this.$store.dispatch('registration/updateFormData', { needCaptcha: needCaptcha });

         const result = await this.$validator.validateAll()
         if (result) {
          this.next()
         }
        } catch (e) {
         console.log(e)
        }
        this.registrationButtonDisabled = false
       }
```

Problem:

On some mobile Chromes (Version 7), when you start typing in the input field the field instantly resets and validates with error. Note:

- This does NOT happen on all Version 7 Chromes, depending on the device
- If you attach a keyboard to the phone it works
- It only behaves that way if the first input to that field after initialization is done via Touch-Keyboard. If you type with normal keyboard, reset the field, and type with Touch-Keyboard if works.
- **If you dont't type but instead use the Touch-Keyboards suggestions it validates correctly but remains empty. The filled-Class is set in that case. That makes us think that the model is set, validated, and then resetted for some strange reason.**

This is obviously hard to debug, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is a bug in Vee-Validate. On some mobile devices, the `$watch-API` is handeled differently, meaning the `v-model` is not updating in realtime. `v-validate` can't handle this.

A workaround would be to add `data-vv-validate-on="blur"` to the input, to make vee wait  until the model is actually set.

Despite the developers making promises months ago, it seems unclear wheather this will ever get fixed.

Here is a link to the GitHub-Discussion on this: https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/1281#issuecomment-399920810

The problem seems to concern Chrome on some devices, unrelated to the used version and also Safari. Firefox seems stable